# Retrieve uttered intent and slot type from Alexa request in c# service

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I've got a c# service running on AWS Lambda, the FunctionHandler is receiving the request properly and distinguishes between a Launch type and Intent type. As in the title though, how do I get to what the user actually inputted?

The intent is called 'swap_screens', the sample utterance is 'switch screen to {display}' and the custom slot has options of 'computer' or 'television'.

How do I pick out 'computer' or 'television'?

```
private SkillResponse skillResponse = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>

    public SkillResponse FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext ctx)
    {
        if (input.GetRequestType() == typeof(LaunchRequest))
        {
            skillResponse = LaunchRequestHandler(input);
        }
        else if (input.GetRequestType() == typeof(IntentRequest))
        {
            skillResponse = IntentRequestHandler(input);
        }


        return skillResponse;
    }

    private SkillResponse LaunchRequestHandler(SkillRequest skillRequest)
    {
        var skillResponse = new SkillResponse
        {
            Version = "1.0",
            Response = new ResponseBody()
        };

        skillResponse.Response.OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech
        {
            Text = "Launch."
        };

        return skillResponse;
    }

    private SkillResponse IntentRequestHandler(SkillRequest skillRequest)
    {
        var skillResponse = new SkillResponse
        {
            Version = "1.0",
            Response = new ResponseBody()
        };

        skillResponse.Response.OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech
        {
            Text = "Intent."
        };

        return skillResponse;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Like this;

`var intentRequest = (IntentRequest)skillRequest.Request;
string strSlotValue = intentRequest.Intent.Slots["slot name"].Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Here i am assuming that you may have more than one slots in same intent/utterance.

Alexa request converts all the slot value in array, so you can access the slot value using below code.(here "date" is my slot name)

```
       if (intentRequest.Intent.Slots.TryGetValue("date", out var dateSlot))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateSlot.Value))
                {
                   //Slot value
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hello. It's the now deprecated 'literal' I was after.